# IntelliJ does not recognize imports from sources of maven libraries

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When I navigate to an in-house library class, the decompiled source's import statements work fine, but when I specify the local directory containing the actual sources of the library, the source file opens but the imports fail there. This problem doesn't occur for the JDK or sources from central maven repositories.

For example, in `import a.b.Clazz`, `Clazz` is recognized in the decompiled source but not in the actual source from a local directory (`Cannot resolve symbol 'Clazz'`).

Any ideas? (no pun intended)

Version: IDEA 14.1.3 Ultimate. Libraries specified via Maven.

Comment: try maven > re import

Comment: or invalidate caches

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that may be causing the issue is that the libraries you installed aren't added to the classpath, and once you do that Intellij will recognize all the libraries.